# X,Y,W,H of external window in QT

Tags: c++, qt, winapi

I am learning to program and am having trouble with finding position and resolution data in Qt/Windows. I have c++ functions that can do it.

Here is the Qt code I am working with

```
void Edge_Window::on_pushButton_getInfo_6_clicked()
{
    HWND h = FindWindow(NULL, TEXT("Edge Organizer"));
    LPRECT rct;
    GetWindowRect(h, rct);
    qDebug() << "X = " << rct->left;
    qDebug() << "Y = " << rct->top;
    qDebug() << "Width = " << rct->right - rct->left;
    qDebug() << "Height = " << rct->bottom - rct->top;
}
```

Unfortunately the only answer I get from the debug is:

```
X =  1693732235
Y =  3465
Width =  644133493
Height =  79843420
```

This is the response no matter where my screen is located. I tried `GetForegroundWindow()` but it just crashes. My goal is to grab info like title, class, coords And resolution as well as to be able to set them on external programs in Windows.

Comment: Do you check what's `HWND h` value after `FindWindow()` function call? It can be NULL (windows isn't found), so your rectangle will not be properly initialized.

Comment: I received a value of 0x2350a8a that changes everytime i restart the program so i would assume there is a some sort of communication happening

Comment: Qt seems to be a read herring here. You're using solely the Win32 interface. That's correct, of course. You have no idea whether the other window was made with Qt, just that it's a Win32 window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code `rct` is an uninitialized pointer to `RECT`

You want this instead:

```
RECT rct;
GetWindowRect(h, &rct);
```

As `rct` is no longer a pointer but a `RECT`, you also need to change all `rct->xxx` to `rct.xxx`.

Your original code is equivalent to this:

```
RECT *rct;   // now it's a bit more obvious that rct is an uninitialized pointer
GetWindowRect(h, rct);
```

Comment: I am new to this forum and it is not so intuitive. I was able to resolve the issue by your request and updating a few parts to properly point to rect.( rct->top to rct.top)

Comment: @DavidArmijo yes, hiding pointers behind typedefs is not the best idea. Each time you see a `LPxxx` in Windows is means actually "pointer to `xxx`".